# How to create a matrix of numbers from matrix of textboxes?

Tags: c#, winforms

I create a matrix of textboxes and then I want to create a similar size matrix with their values.

This matrix has 3 lines and N columns, where N is read from special textbox.

```
        void NUbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int x = 590, y = 125;
            if (int.TryParse(NUtext.Text, out int NU) == true)
            {
                TextBox[,] tabl = new TextBox[NU, 3];
                for (int i = 0; i < NU; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                    {
                        tabl[i, j] = new TextBox();
                        tabl[i, j].SuspendLayout();
                        tabl[i, j].Location = new Point(x, y);
                        tabl[i, j].Size = new Size(70, 33);
                        tabl[i, j].Visible = true;
                        Controls.Add(tabl[i, j]);
                        y = y + 60;
                    }
                    x = x + 80;
                    y = 125;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Input number must be integer");
            }
        }
```

It successfully creates textboxes. Then i want to create a matrix with numbers from textboxes and check are they in correct type (tr[,] and tabl[,] are public)

```
        void Calcbutton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bool check = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < double.Parse(NUtext.Text); i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                {
                    if (double.TryParse(tabl[i, j].Text, out double tt) == true) //NULL!!!!!
                    {
                        tr[i, j] = tt;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        check = false;
                    }
                }
                if (check == true)
                {
                //calculations
                }
            }
        }
```

But it returns System.NullReferenceException, despite textboxes are not empty. How can I fix that?

Comment: `TextBox[,] tabl = new TextBox[NU, 3];` You have created a local variable here. You probably just want `tabl = new TextBox[NU, 3];`